# Undefined variable $consultation

Tags: php, laravel, web

I want display my data to my blade file but it show this error

```
Undefined variable $consultation
```

This is my controller

```
 public function p_consultation()
 {
     $consultation = Consultation::all();
     return view ('dashboard/admin_panel/p_consultation')->with( $consultation);
 }
```

This is my Route

```
Route::get('dashboard/admin_panel/p_consultation', [PenconsultationController::class, 'Consultation'])
```

And this is my Blade File

```
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                    <th>Dscriptiom</th>
                                    <th>Material</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Start Date</th>
                                    <th>End Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($consultation as $consultation)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->item_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->description }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->material }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->quantity }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->start_date }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $consultation->end_date }}</td>
                                  </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: `foreach($consultation as $consultation)` - first iteration overwrites your array element. Don't do that, very dangerous and can lead to hidden bugs.

Comment: `->with( $consultation);` must be `->with('consultation', $consultation);` - you don't pass variable name into view. See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing data to the controller using [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views), you need to bind it with an accessor.

```
->with('consultation', $consultation)

return view('dashboard/admin_panel/p_consultation')->with('consultation', $consultation);
```

You can use `compact()` as well

---

Example.

```
return view('greeting')
            ->with('name', 'Victoria')
            ->with('occupation', 'Astronaut');
```

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
return view ('dashboard/admin_panel/p_consultation')->with( $consultation);
```

to

```
return view ('dashboard/admin_panel/p_consultation', ['consultation' => $consultation]);
```